# ASP.Net form in master page an on a child page

Tags: asp.net, winforms

I have defined a `MasterPage` in ASP web project. There I have a top bar with a search field:

```
<div class="top-bar">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder_header" runat="server">
    <div class="header search">
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
    </div>
  </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

<!-- Body content. -->
<div id="content">
  <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder_BodyContent" runat="server" />
</div>
```

On a separate field, I have a login form:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID = "ContentPlaceHolder_BodyContent"
    runat="server">
    <form id="AuthenticationForm" class="login-register-form" method="POST" runat="server">
    </form> 
</asp:Content>
```

The problem is that I need a form at the login page, but I want to show it inside the body placeholder.

I'm getting the error that `asp:TextBox` should be inside a form, but as far as I know, it's not possible to have multiple forms in the same page at the same time in ASP.

Comment: *"I need a form at the login page"* - The entire page is always one big form in WebForms.  You can't nest forms inside of other forms.  Why do you think you need an explicit `<form>` element here?  Your login inputs will post back to the code-behind like any other inputs, there's no need for a manual `<form>` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.Net WebForms is designed to only have one form per page, so remove the form tags from the login page and make sure the master page has all controls inside the form tags:

```
<form>
  <div class="top-bar">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder_header" runat="server">
      <div class="header search">
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server" />
      </div>
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
  </div>

  <!-- Body content. -->
  <div id="content">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder_BodyContent" runat="server" />
  </div>
</form>
```